# use pandas in sqlite query in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlite

I made mistake.I used pandas after

```
j=("SELECT sth FROM table WHERE rowid = ? ", (index,))
df1 = pd.read_sql_query(j, conn)
```

index is a number So I have got an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1401, in execute
    cur.execute(*args)
ValueError: operation parameter must be str

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dialog.py", line 142, in Ayat
    df1 = pd.read_sql_query(j, conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 331, in read_sql_query
    parse_dates=parse_dates, chunksize=chunksize)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1436, in read_query
    cursor = self.execute(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1413, in execute
    raise_with_traceback(ex)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 340, in raise_with_traceback
    raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1401, in execute
    cur.execute(*args)
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql '<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f6338146730>': operation parameter must be str
```

If I don't use pandas it is OK and functioning with no problem

Comment: You're passing what looks like a tuple as `j` and `pd.read_sql_query` is expecting a string.

Comment: Thanks to owen79 but  the solution I posted my self maybe notable for you.

Answer (score 0):

That  is not the way of using pandas with sqlite.
the correct is :

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('File.db')
m = 1
query = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE priority = {0};".format(m)

df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)

for * in df['*']:
  print('{}'.format(*))
```

Anyway thanks for help of owen79